# Cannot authenticate user in Symfony 6.2 using AccessToken

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, symfony-security, symfony6

I'm building an API application with Symfony 6.2 and trying to use Access Tokens for stateless authentication. As suggested in [symfony docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_token.html) I have implemented AccessTokenHandler class

```
<?php
# src\Security\AccessTokenHandler.php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Repository\AccessTokenRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\BadCredentialsException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\AccessToken\AccessTokenHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\UserBadge;

class AccessTokenHandler implements AccessTokenHandlerInterface {
    public function __construct( private AccessTokenRepository $repository
    ) {
    }

    public function getUserBadgeFrom( string $accessToken ): UserBadge {
        // e.g. query the "access token" database to search for this token
        $accessToken = $this->repository->findValidToken($accessToken);

        if ( NULL === $accessToken || !$accessToken->isValid() ) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException( 'Invalid credentials.' );
        }

        /* DEBUG: UNCOMMENT FOR DEBUG 
        dump($accessToken);die; 
        /* DEBUG /**/

        // and return a UserBadge object containing the user identifier from the found token
        return new UserBadge( $accessToken->getUserId() );
    }
}
```

and configured my `security.yaml` file

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#registering-the-user-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#loading-the-user-the-user-provider
    providers:
        access_token_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\AccessToken
                property: tokenValue
    firewalls:
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: access_token_provider
            stateless: true
            pattern: ^/api
            access_token:
                token_extractors: header
                token_handler: App\Security\AccessTokenHandler
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/api, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

In the database there is the only user in `User` table and related token in `AccessToken` table.

To test the above I'm using Postman to send a GET request to `https://my-host/api/test-page` with the following header:

```
Authorization: Bearer 59e4fb3f9c10e0fe570d486462ab417a
```

It gets into *AccessTokenHandler::getUserBadgeFrom* as expected and returns the correct token with user (see the commented debug code on *AccessTokenHandler:23*).

Yet, the request returns status code `401 Unauthorized` with `WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token",error_description="Invalid credentials."` header.

Comment: Investigate why `$accessToken->isValid() === false`

Comment: @Justinas `$accessToken->isValid()` returns `true` and it gets correctly to the very end of `getUserBadgeFrom` returning the valid token with related user in it. Checked this with the commented debug code. 
Another thing notices, that changing Exception message does not affect `error_description` text. So I suspect that some another authentication mechanism runs after AccessTokenHandler jet don't know how to check\fix it.

Comment: If you are using step debugger (xDebug) go further until you hit where error is thrown, than look around to investigate what's wrong

Comment: I have the same problem, any solutions yet?

Comment: @pnine yep! I found the problem. see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to figure out what the issue was. The above configuration is almost correct; however, a Symfony security component was missing a proper user provider to retrieve a User record even though it had the correct identifier (AccessToken).

So I had to do following steps to get the things working:

**Step #1:** Implement `AccessTokenUserProvider` class as follows:

```
<?php
# src\Security\AccessTokenUserProvider.php

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UserNotFoundException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;

class AccessTokenUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $userRepository;

    public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    }

    public function loadUserByIdentifier(string $identifier): UserInterface
    {
        $user = $this->userRepository->findOneByAccessToken($identifier);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new UserNotFoundException();
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        return $this->loadUserByIdentifier($user->getUserIdentifier());
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class === User::class;
    }
}
```

**Step #2:** Register user provider in `services.yaml`

```
services:
    # ....
    app.access_token_user_provider:
        class: App\Security\AccessTokenUserProvider
        arguments: ['@App\Repository\UserRepository']
```

**Step #3:** and finally configure its usage in `security.yaml`:

```
security:
    # ....
    providers:
        access_token_provider:
            id: app.access_token_user_provider
    # ....
    firewalls:
        api:
            lazy: true
            provider: access_token_provider
            stateless: true
            pattern: ^/api
            access_token:
                token_extractors: header
                token_handler: App\Security\AccessTokenHandler
```

And this is it! Now Symfony uses our AccessTokenUserProvider to load corresponding user record from the database.

I hope this will save time for anyone who follows the same path! :)

Answer (score 0):

From the Documentation

> The UserBadge requires a user identifier (e.g. the username or email), which is used to load the user using the user provider

Here you are giving `userId` in `UserBadge` instead of `tokenValue` that is used in your access_token_provider configuration.